# Changing descriptive statistics parameters in a map. R

Tags: r, maps

I create a UK map representing some info by downloading an Spatial Polygons Data Frame from GADM.org and the following script.

```
lat<-c(51.5163,52.4847,51.4544,53.5933,51.481389,51.367778,55.953056,55.864167,51.482778)
lon<-c(-0.061389,-1.89,-2.587778,-2.296389,-3.178889,-0.07,-3.188056,-4.251667,-0.388056)
fr<-c(0.004278509,0.004111901,0.004150415,0.00421649,0.004221205,0.004191472,0.004507773,0.004314193,0.004098154)
uk<-data.frame(cbind(lat,lon,fr))
plotvar<-uk$fr
nclr<-4
plotclr <- brewer.pal(nclr,"Blues")
max.symbol.size=6
min.symbol.size=1
class <- classIntervals(plotvar, nclr, style="quantile")
colcode <- findColours(class, plotclr)
symbol.size <- ((plotvar-min(plotvar))/
              (max(plotvar)-min(plotvar))*(max.symbol.size-min.symbol.size)
            +min.symbol.size)
windows()
par(mai=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(UnK, col = 'lightgrey', border = 'darkgrey',xlim=c(-6,0),ylim=c(50,60)) #Unk is the map downloaded from GADM
points(uk$lon, uk$lat, col=2, pch=18)
points(uk$lon, uk$lat, pch=16, col=colcode, cex=symbol.size)
points(uk$lon, uk$lat, cex = symbol.size)
text(-120, 46.5, "Area: Frho")
legend(locator(1), legend=names(attr(colcode, "table")),
   fill=attr(colcode, "palette"), cex=1, bty="n")
```

The following figure is the outcome of the above script.

[image]

Now, my problem is that I'm not happy with the colors and the breaks of the variable uk$fr. I need to change then in order to be able to compare this map with others, but I dont know how to do the following. My intention is to break this variable in 3 different classes like this (0-0.0125],(0.0125-0.0625],(0.0625-0.125]. And represent this classes by "Blues" and by different sizes circles. Also I want to force the legend to include these three classes.

One last question, how can I put title to the legend?

Thanks.

Comment: See `?cut` to break the variables. However, your specified breaks are an order of magnitude greater than your data.

Comment: Not exactly, all of my data would be within the break (0-0.0125]. I tried cut() already, but I dont know how to adapt it to this case. Thanks for your input!